# MySQL - Query by day of month

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I have a table that is used as a billing reminder.  Instead of giving the entire due day, I just have the day of the month (i.e. 20) for the 20th of each month.  I am trying to figure out how to query my table so that it will find those that are within the next 5 days.  I have searched, and found solutions that have a whole date, but not where just the day of the month has been provided.

Comment: Did you try adjusting any of the solutions you found already?

Answer (score 0):

Get the current date using:

```
<?php
$day = (date('j') + 5) % 31; // OR % 30
```

Then search through the days in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table where billing_date = $day
```

Comment: Had to use BETWEEN the current day and $day

Will this compensate if today was the 28th to go into the next month?

$day = (date('j') + 5) % 31; // OR % 30

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Bills where DueDay BETWEEN ".date('j')." AND ".$day;